# Is it possible to cancel all running JS functions when destroying a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js

I'm wondering if it's possible to cancel all running async functions belonging to a component when destroying that component. I have a View-component which fetches a lot of data when the user enters that page, the problem is if the user goes to another page before the data is fully loaded, then the request-queue-limit is reached and slows down the data-loading for the new page.

Comment: "running JS functions" is not really correct as technically those functions doesn't run but are waiting for some result (HTTP response for example). But yes, most HTTP clients support request cancellation. Just google it ....

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: Can you please show an example of your load method?

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix this was to just check the lifecycle-status of the component instance. I found out that it was possible to check this._isBeingDestroyed
and this._isDestroyed, and then do an early return.

```js
async fetchDataFunction() {
if (this._isBeingDestroyed || this._isDestroyed) return;

// Code
}
```